# Excel Delete data not in range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of data over many cells.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

and I want the reuslt say I use the args, (range, 3,7)
then the data changes to this range.

```
3,4,5,6,7
```

like this Formula, except that the actual data gets deleted.

```
    Public Function MakeAList(rng As Range, U As Long, L As Long) As String
  Dim r As Range, s As String
  For Each r In rng
    If r.Value < L Or r.Value > U Then
      s = s & "," & r.Value
    End If
  Next r
  MakeAList = Mid(s, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: improve your question and example

Answer (score 0):

Let say Cell `A1` contain `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

Then in `A2` use `=MID(A1,3,7)` , it will take the 3rd to 7th elements inside `A1`.